# Enviar el id de un select (mediante un button) a un input tag mediante JavaScript

Tags: php, html, jquery

la cosa es que estoy trabajando con accesos de los roles y tenia una duda sobre los tags de jQuery, la cosa es que estoy listando un select con los nombres de los permisos ya registrados y quiero asignarle al role una serie de atributos de tipo permiso (esto es los permisos donde tiene acceso el role).

Ok, yo tengo un formulario de ejemplo para no pegar todo el formulario porque es muy grande, pero este es funcional.
El formuario seria asi:

```
<form id="form_create_update_accesos" name="form_create_update_accesos" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <label for="id_permiso">Permisos</label>
    <select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" name="id_permiso" id="id_permiso" required></select>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button" onclick="addAtributo()">
      <i class="fa fa-plus" style="font-size: 12px;"></i>  Agregar Atributo
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <label for="atributo">Atributos de Acceso</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="atributo" name="atributo" data-role="tagsinput" placeholder="Atributos de Acceso" readonly />
  </div>
</form>
```

Ahora coloco la funcion js que estoy indicando el caso.

```
function addAtributo(){
  aux = document.getElementById("id_permiso").value;
  setAcceso(aux);
}
```

Aqui, intento jalar el id del input del select y enviarlo a otra funcion para setear el input de los tags, pero no se como setearlo bien.
Aqui esta la que uso para setear pero algo anda mal.

```
function setAcceso(aux){
  $("#atributo").val(aux).tagsinput({
      confirmKeys: [1, 2],
      maxTags: 3
  });
}
```

Cabe destacar que estoy usando la libreria de javascript para los input tags
seria esta la de js

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.js"></script>
```

Y esta otra es para el estilo css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.css" />
```

En resumen, estoy tratando de el id del select, enviarlo al input de los tags para ir agregrandolos como atributos y luego guardarlos.

Saludos.

Comment: No se entiende bien la pregunta, pero perecería que [hacer uso de los atributos `data`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/como/Usando_atributos_de_datos)  en este caso podría simplificarte la vida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo más cómodo es usar los atributos data.

## Tu código modificado con atributos data

*En este ejemplo solo me he centrado en la lógica de recoger los `data`, no en la lógica de la funcionalidad final del código.*

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script >

function addAtributo(){
  var role = $('#atributo').data('role');
  var otrodata = $('#atributo').data('otrodata');
  var quenecesito = $('#atributo').data('quenecesito');
  console.log('Role: '+role);
  console.log('Otro Data: '+otrodata);
  console.log('Otro Que Necesito: '+quenecesito);
  
}


</script>

<form id="form_create_update_accesos" name="form_create_update_accesos" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <label for="id_permiso">Permisos</label>
    <select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" name="id_permiso" id="id_permiso" required></select>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button" onclick="addAtributo()">
      <i class="fa fa-plus" style="font-size: 12px;"></i>  Agregar Atributo
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <label for="atributo">Atributos de Acceso</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="atributo" name="atributo"
            data-otrodata="otro data cualquiera"
            data-quenecesito="Este data me guarda otro dato"
            data-role="tagsinput" placeholder="Atributos de Acceso" readonly />
  </div>
</form>
```

Si te fijas en el `Input` he incluido varios `data` de pruebas.

En los `data`puedes ir almacenando datos que luego necesites en tu JQuery. Es una buena forma de pasar variables de PHP => JS

Con este replanteamiento del código seguramente lo simplificas y tendrás un código con variables más descriptivas.

*Espero que te sirva.*